# section titles, cyrillic and hyperref

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cyrillic

I need to use cyrillic. I hacked from somewhere the def of `\textcyrw` you see below. Everything works fine, but when I need to use `\textcyrw` within a section title. It seems that the culprit is [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Your advise is welcome.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american,russian,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} % no problem without hyperref

\newcommand\cyrillic{%
\renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
\renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
\renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
\normalfont
\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyrillic}

\begin{document}
\section{AAA}
\textcyr{Личное дело} % works fine
\section{\textcyr{Личное дело}} % gives error
\end{document}
```

The error message I got is:

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.- \section{\textcyr{Личное дело}}
```

----- fixed

the following fixed it, although I am not sure why:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
\let\textcyr\relax}
```

Answer (score 3):

OT2 is really an outdated way to produce Cyrillic text. Since you seem to be able to input Russian text directly, it's better to use `T2A`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american,russian,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} % no problem without hyperref

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textcyr}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{AAA}
\textcyr{Личное дело} % works fine
\section{\textcyr{Личное дело}} % gives error
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a little problem. When I use this code I get http://i.imgur.com/3ER3Gtp.png. Problem is that lines are not smooth enough like in your example. How to fix it? I use `pdflatex`, because with `LuaLatex` or `XeLatex` I only get: "1 AAA 2" and nothing else. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Cortizol You probably don't have installed the CM-Super font package; it's common among MiKTeX users. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I use basic-miktex-2.9.4813.

Comment: @Cortizol Install the CM-Super package: http://miktex.org/packages/cm-super

Comment: I installed it from here (because I didn't see download button in your link): http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super/. I copied from `pfb` file in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\public\cm-super, like they said in Install.tex file, but when I run program I can't see any difference. But that is probably because I don't know to install package properly.

Comment: @Cortizol You have to use the MiKTeX wizard for this, not installing manually from CTAN

Comment: I didn't know that. I came to the part http://i.imgur.com/62sT9A3.png, but I don't know what to choose (I don't see CM-super)? Or to live like this (all chosen)? Thank you for help